# SystemDialogInput seems to malfunction

Tags: files-and-directories

If I execute

```
SystemDialogInput["FileOpen"]
```

a file browser is opened. If I choose a .txt or .html file, all is well and the file name is returned. But if I choose a .jpg or .tif file, Mathematica quits.

Something seems very wrong... are others having this problem? This is on Mac OS 10.13.2, Mathematica 11.2. My older Mac with OS 10.11.6 and Mathematica 11.1.1 doesn't have this issue. Is a bug or an idiosyncrasy of my system?

Comment: fyi, no crash in 11.2 on windows 7. Tried with .jpg file. Nothing happened after selecting the file, it just returned the file name in the notebook.

Comment: I can not reproduce your problem in V11.1.1 running on OS X 10.10.2

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I cannot reproduce the problem the user is experiencing.

Comment: @m_goldberg but has anyone tried in  Mac OS 10.13.2?